# jQuery live(), 1 mouse clicked but I got 2 events?

Tags: jquery, events, click, live

I'm getting some weird thing happening with my javascript. I'm fetching data from the server side, and when the result come back, I update my div with the data in my table.
I then call postUpdate and bind a function to every rows in the table.

```
jQuery.fn.postUpdate = function(id) {
    console.log('postUpdate with id: '+id);
    if (id == "myContent") {
        jQuery('#DataTable tr').live(
                'click',
                function(event) {
                    jQuery.fn.showDetails(event);                        
        });
    }
};    

jQuery.fn.showDetails = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

However, everytime I click on the row, I'm getting the event printed twice?

```
Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=351233505, more...} base.js (line 181)
Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=351233505, more...} base.js (line 181)
```

What's the deal here? Bug in jQuery?

Comment: You shouldn't be hanging your own functions off of `jQuery.fn`.  Just declare functions called `postUpdate` and `showDetails`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `postUpdate`, you add an additional live handler.

Once you're using `live`, you should not re-add handlers every time you add elements, since the handlers will apply to all matching elements.

Comment: But my div gets clear everytime I fetch a new query. On top of that, it was only the first time i populate the table.

I don't think I'm re-adding anything handler, because everytime I query for new data, the existing content in my div gets wipe out, and new one is fed back in. I'm still getting 2 events per mouse click.

Comment: @codenamezero: `live` has nothing to do with the lifetime of the elements.  If you called the function at page load too, this would explain it.

Comment: Thanks Slaks, I went and tried to call the live when ready(), and the function got registered. jQuery is so mysterious... can bind functions to elements that aren't even in the DOM! Thanks a lot.

Comment: `live` works through event bubbling; it handles the event in the `body` and checks where it bubbled from.  It's one of jQuery's most powerful features.  You can use traditional event handling (to existing elements) by calling `bind`.  You should read more about these.